# Debian packaging changing file

Tags: debian, deb, software-packaging

I am currently in the progress of packaging a binary file and have all of the directories setup and ready to package.

When I package the file using the debuild -b command the script works and creates a debian package but I notice when I do a SHA1 sum of the files after I extract them from the deb for testing are different to those which it is generated from.

Is there a way to fix this?

This is due to the fact that the original files work on the system but the same files then do not work on the same identical system once the debuild process has been run.

Comment: That is strange. You'll probably need to give more information about what how your packaging works (is it debhelper?) and what sort of files these are.

Comment: I used the tutorials at http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/. The binary files are from cxfreeze'd python scripts.

Comment: Perhaps the binaries are simply having debug symbols stripped by `dh_strip`. To confirm, could you include the output of `file path/to/your/binary` for both versions of the binaries: before packaging, and inside the package.